# Motion layout not working when Exoplayer touched

Tags: exoplayer, android-motionlayout

Please help me as I have been facing issues in the motion layout for the past few days. I am trying to implement Youtube like collapsing animation and playing stream using Exoplayer. Everything works fine but the problem is when the view is expanded and the player view touch It will only change the visibility of exoplayer controls and animation doesn't work. Animation only works when I set
`playerview.setUseController(false)`
But I don't want to change the default behavior of player controls. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67227378/13050313) will help you maybe.