# MotionLayout with Exoplayer handle touch events not properly

Tags: android, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I have `OnSwipe` animation in Motion Layout and a ExoPlayer. But when exoplayer is playing, motion layout animation not working. I think ExoPlayer intercepting touch events. How can i solve this issue? For example Youtube application handle swipe and also click events

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple Way of doing that
Extends the **MotionLayout** class and by overriding the

> onInterceptTouchEvent()

```
 @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

this is a simplest way to pass Childs touch event to parent or to background layout.
this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by creating custom player view. The problem is PlayerView intercepting the touch event, so motion layout don't get any touch event. By changing return value at PlayerView.onTouchEvent from true to false, the motion layout can handle the swipe event.

```
internal class CustomExoPlayerView(
    context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null
) : PlayerView(context, attributeSet) {

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                showController()
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```